# What is a good alternative to CFRelease for Core Foundation objects?

Tags: objective-c

I have taken to the following code which will call CFRelease after a delay. I have included it in a method for context.

```
CGPathRef NewPathWithRoundRect(CGRect rect, CGFloat cornerRadius)
{
     // other work to create ref which is a CGPath
     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        CFRelease(ref);
    });
}
```

In the latest version of Xcode I get a warning about not releasing memory properly. The caller takes the value, uses it and then calls CFRelease. I now CFRetain it and also CFRelease it so in order to get the reference count down to zero I am setting this dispatch to run and clean up the reference.

I am not comfortable with this approach. Is there is a better pattern for returning CF objects that were created in the method and need to be returned? Should I create the path outside the method and pass it in as a parameter so it is created and released by the caller?

I have also changed my code to call CGPathRelease which is a little safer. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CoreFoundation policy is that if a function has the word "Create" in it, then the function returns an owning (or retained) object, which the caller is responsible for releasing. So your `NewPathWithRoundRect` method should be named `CreatePathWithRoundRect`, and then just drop the delayed CFRelease. The caller will be responsible for releasing it when they're done with it.